# Django Select Drop Down menu Flow

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

What I'm trying to do is a 2 tier search with drop down menus using Select widget, the results will be a listing of the fields from my Meta.model. the first Tier is a a State listing from State.model. Upon a select it is supposed to list out all of the cities with in the selected state, the problem I'm having (and I think its due to my lack of knowledge) is that the city listing is not filtered but a listing of all cities in my database regardless of state. I'm not sure where or how to pass my variable to be able invoke my .filter() statement.

models.py

```
 class Meta(models.Model):
     rcabbr             = models.CharField(max_length = 15)
     slug               = models.SlugField(unique=False)
     state              = models.ForeignKey('State')
     rc_state           = models.CharField(max_length = 3)
     oerp               = models.CharField(max_length=18)
     subgrp             = models.SlugField()
     sonus_pic          = models.CharField(max_length=8)
     ems                    = models.CharField(max_length=14)
     agc                    = models.CharField(max_length=14)

     def __unicode__(self):
         return self.rcabbr

 class State(models.Model):
     name               = models.CharField(max_length=2)
     slug               = models.SlugField(unique=True)
     state_long         = models.CharField(max_length=15)
     owning_site            = models.CharField(max_length=12)

     def __unicode__(self):
         return self.name
         return self.state_long
```

forms.py

```
class states(forms.Form):
     invent = [(k.name,k.state_long) for k in State.objects.all()]
     rclist = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.Select, choices=invent)


class rateCenter(forms.Form):
     invention = [(k.id,k.rcabbr,k.rc_state) for k in Meta.objects.all()]
     rcviews = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.Select, choices=invention)
```

views.py

```
 def StateAll(request):
     """ This lists out all of the states within the database that
         are served"""
     rclist = states()
     return render(request, 'statelist.html',{'rclist': rclist})


 def RcView(request):
     """ this should list all the rateCenters within 
            the state that was selected in StateAll() """
     rclist = request.GET['rclist'] 
     forms = rateCenter()
     return render(request, 'rclist.html',{'forms': forms})
```

Logic tells me I should to do my .filter() statement in the forms.py but unsure how to pass the result from the request.GET in StateAll() view. I do have the debug_toolbar installed so I can see the variable u'rclist' and the value u'LA' (my test state).  I had this working 100% using hyperlinks however the size of my test database is miniscule in comparison to what is going to be in the production version and HREF's are just not possible.

my understanding is:

```
 ChainedForeignKey(LinkedModel, LinkedModel.field = "field in first Tier", chained_model_field = "current model_field")
```

so simple model should I think be something like this?

```
 def State(model.models):
      name = models.CharField(max_length=20) #this is the state abbreviation
      state_long = models.CharFeild(max_length=20)#this is state long form

 def Meta(model.models):
      state = models.CharField(max_length=20)
      slug = models.SlugField(unique = False) #same values as rcabbr
      rcabbr =  ChainedForeignKey(State, chained_field = "state_long", 
           chained_model_field = "slug")
      .....
```

Does that look about right........so the First Field in the drop down should be the State_long, once selected the next should be the slug?. at which time the slug should be passed to my urls and the views for the that final page.

I am going to try this however I'm not 100% sure how to do my views and if I need to do something with forms page or does this cover it? The documentation is not user friendly for someone new to this so any input would be most appreciated!

Comment: Try this out, it's a beauty and super easy. JavaScript/AJAX is automatically created to do exactly what you're seeking (see ChainedForeignKey)

Comment: [Django-smart-selects]( https://github.com/digi604/django-smart-selects)

Comment: just installed it, reading through how to impliment now. thank you. I'll get back to you on results. appreciate it!!!

Comment: I've used it many times, happy to post an example of how to create the field for your models tomorrow if you run into troouble

Comment: that would be great, I'll play with it some tonight and post tomorrow my progress!!

Comment: okay just getting back to this. the example on github is rather cryptic but I think I get have an understanding of the relationship. so if you can tell me if I'm on track that would be great... I've put it above so its easier to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many third party libraries [django-smart-selects](https://github.com/digi604/django-smart-selects) and [dajax](http://www.dajaxproject.com/forms/) come to mind - that will automate this for you along with provide you the necessary javascript to filter the form fields on the fly.

If you are investigating those, here is how you would do it with just the django forms:

```
class RateCenterForm(forms.Form):
    rate_center = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Meta.objects.all())

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       state = kwargs.pop('state')
       super(RaterCenterForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
       self.fields['rate_center'].queryset = Meta.objects.filter(state=state)
```

A [`ModelChoiceField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield) is a select drop down that takes its values from a model.

Now in your view, you would call it like this:

```
def show_rate_centers(request):
    form = RateCenterForm(state='SomeState')
    # .. your normal logic here
```

Comment: Getting closer I have looked but dont understand the def __init__ portion. I'm getting an error now that I've not had before "Unknown column 'meta_meta.rcabbr_id' in 'field list'" not sure where its coming from as I've not defined it anywhere.

Comment: Since you are passing an argument `state` which is not something that you would normally pass to the form, you need to override the `__init__` method to remove this extra argument (the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/forms/fields/#fields-which-handle-relationships) has more on this) as for your second part - that probably has to do with `ChainedForeignKey`.

Comment: great thank you! I'll have to do more research on the foreign key. I modified the db to rcabbr_id and then I get an error that the id field is invalid so there is something confused somewhere. I'll do more research thank you for your input. its greatly appreciated!

Comment: You don't want to use both ChainedForeignKey and what I posted, use one or the other - using both will further create problems.

Comment: I'm not sure where your getting the 'SomeState' from. I'm passing the variable rclist in the response.GET statement so I would assume that my statement should be form = RateCenterForm(state='rclist') to which I'm still getting unexpected kwarg